# Boom, in Hapi, in NodeJS app, is hiding my problems from me

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I just started working on an API, which is a NodeJS app, which uses Hapi, which in turn uses Boom. Boom is great, but it hides from me some errors that I would like to see.

Working locally on my Mac, I open 2 terminal windows. In one terminal I run "npm start" which gets the API running locally. In the other terminal, I test the API with this cURL call:

```
curl 'http://needi.local:8080/search/uber' -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnc'
```

And that works great! I get all the data I expect.

So now I put this inside of a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ sh
curl 'http://needi.local:8080/search/uber' -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'x-api-key: 2gt7Pt2LU194KKcNnc'
```

Now I run this and instead of getting the data, I get this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     
Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    
Left  Speed

100   109  100   109    0     0   3858      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- 
--:--:--  3892

{

  "statusCode": 500,

  "error": "Internal Server Error",


  "message": "An internal server error occurred"

}
```

This message appears to be generated from Boom. When I grep the code I only see this message coming from Boom. The message is described here:

https://github.com/hapijs/boom

That's all good, up to a point. Given a problem, Boom should send back that message. That's fine.

But whatever the problem is, it never shows up in the other terminal window, where I am running the app. I expect a stacktrace to show up, but it doesn't.

So perhaps Boom swallows the error? How can I get the error to appear in the log (the terminal that is running the API).

Or perhaps Boom is innocent. Perhaps this is simply a case of an Exception that is not being caught?

Comment: Boom sends error to the client. It isn't responsible for managing it on server side. 500 means that error happened on server side. I would expect to see console output, but this depends on the error. See more on logging http://hapijs.com/tutorials/logging#configuration .

Comment: Yes as @estus says the error will normally be due to some programming error so I would expect output from the servers terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the way boom is implemented in your JavaScript files.

According to the [official](https://hapi.dev/module/boom/api/) boom documentation:

> All 500 errors hide your message from the end user.

Furthermore, the docs explain what happens if no status code is set in a boom object:

> Defaults to 500 if no status code is already set.

This defaulting to a 500 error code is a security measure to prevent the actual error from being exposed to clients.